# a bug of merge sort using Python

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, merge

I am working on merge sort using recursive Python.
I couldn't find out where I made mistake and always got wrong answers.
The code is as follows:

```
def mergeSort(xlist):
    print ('Splitting',xlist, len(xlist))
    if len(xlist)>1:
       midpoint = len(xlist) // 2
       left  = xlist[:midpoint]
       right = xlist[midpoint:]
       print ('----------------------------')
       mergeSort(left)
       mergeSort(right)

       print (left, 'r', right)

       while len(right) >0:
          left.append(right[0])
          right.remove(right[0])
          slot= len(left)-1
          while slot >0:
              if left[slot] < left[slot-1]: left[slot], left[slot-1] = left[slot-1], left[slot]
              slot -= 1

       print ('sorted',left, right,xlist)
       return left

print('A',mergeSort([100,1,91,54]))
```

When merging, the output also shows in the wrong way, like:

```
 Splitting [100, 1, 91, 54] 
 ---------------------------- 
 Splitting [100, 1] 2
 ---------------------------- 
 Splitting [100] 1 
 Splitting [1] 1 
 [100] r [1] 
 sorted [1, 100] [] [100, 1]
 Splitting [91, 54] 2
 ---------------------------- 
 Splitting [91] 1 
 Splitting [54] 1 
 [91] r [54] 
 sorted [54, 91] [] [91, 54]
 [100, 1] r [91, 54] 
 sorted [1, 54, 100, 91] [] [100, 1, 91, 54]
 A [1, 54, 100, 91]
```

I expect the last third line should be "[1,100] r [54, 91]" after return back.
What is wrong here? I know there is a code in interactivePython.org, but I wish to understand where I made logical mistake. Can anyone help me? A ton of thanks!

Comment: If `len(xlist)>1` is not true, the function does nothing, therefore it returns None.  Is this intentional?

Comment: The second half of your code is not really doing a merge sort. Appending to `left` is not merging - it's relying on your cleanup code to *sloooowly* arrange the list in correct order. You have effectively implemented a **shell sort** in the guise of merge sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether your `mergesort` code is going to modify the list it is passed in place, or if it is going to return a new list. The top part of your code is written as if it will modify the list in place. The bottom half is written as if it returns a new list. They both need to work the same way, or the sort won't work.

If you want to stick with the modify-in-place approach, the top part of the code is fine, it's just the merging of `left` and `right` at the end that you need to fix up. Instead of merging into `left`, you need to merge into `xlist`. I'd suggest using separate indexes into each of the three lists, rather than doing costly insertions into `left` like you're currently doing.

If you want to return a new list, you need to change the top part of the code. If you hit the base case (`len(xlist) < 2`), you need to return `xlist` unmodified. You also need to save the return values from the recursive calls, perhaps with `left = mergesort(left)` and `right = mergesort(right)`. Your later merging code is probably OK, though it discards most of the performance advantages of merge sort, since the insertion logic is `O(N**2)`.

Comment: I have actually tried to revise my code as adding "xlist = left" just right before "print ('sorted',left, right,xlist)" and remove "return left". This is the modify-in place approach, but it still does not work.

Comment: `xlist = left` won't modify the list pointed to by `xlist`, it just rebinds the name. You could do `xlist[:] = left`, but it would really be better to merge the values from `left` and `right` into `xlist` directly (your current merge procedure is very inefficient).

Comment: Thank you! It works now. What is the difference between xlist =left and xlist[:] = left? Also thank you for your reminder that my current merge procedure is not efficient at all.

Comment: `xlist = left` rebinds the name `xlist` to refer to the same object as `left`. Using a slice assignment on the other hand modifies the contents of the existing `xlist` object, so it still refers to the same object, but has different contents.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few minutes, but I found it.  You recur on the left & right halves properly, but then you throw away the results and merge the original lists.  Correction:

```
    print ('----------------------------')
    left  = mergeSort(left)
    right = mergeSort(right)
```

I expect you can see the effect now.

---

Here's the working code that produced the output above:

```
def mergeSort(xlist):
    print 'Splitting', xlist, len(xlist)
    if len(xlist) <= 1:
        return xlist
    else:
        midpoint = len(xlist) // 2
        left  = xlist[:midpoint]
        right = xlist[midpoint:]
        print ('----------------------------')
        left  = mergeSort(left)
        right = mergeSort(right)

        print left, 'r', right

        # print "merge", left, right
        while len(right) > 0:
            left.append(right[0])
            right.remove(right[0])
            slot = len(left) - 1
            while slot > 0:
                if left[slot] < left[slot-1]:
                    left[slot], left[slot-1] = left[slot-1], left[slot]
                # print "switched", left
                slot -= 1

        print 'sorted', left, right, xlist
        return left

print 'A',mergeSort([100,1,91,54])
```

Output:

```
A Splitting [100, 1, 91, 54] 4
----------------------------
Splitting [100, 1] 2
----------------------------
Splitting [100] 1
Splitting [1] 1
[100] r [1]
sorted [1, 100] [] [100, 1]
Splitting [91, 54] 2
----------------------------
Splitting [91] 1
Splitting [54] 1
[91] r [54]
sorted [54, 91] [] [91, 54]
[1, 100] r [54, 91]
sorted [1, 54, 91, 100] [] [100, 1, 91, 54]
[1, 54, 91, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you! but actually i have tried to do the way you suggested, which shows the following error messages (I used ipython):  
.....
<ipython-input-51-f8eb0c21b2b6> in mergeSort(xlist)
     12         print (left, 'r', right)
     13 
---> 14         while len(right) >0:
     15             left.append(right[0])
     16             right.remove(right[0])

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()